# /system/bin/sh: sm: not found in Samsung Galaxy J1 Ace

Tags: android, adb, samsung-mobile, mobile-phones

I have a Samsung Galaxy J1 Ace and wanted to increase my storage for apps by configuring my SD card. I tried to follow the steps that this video indicates: [Use your SD Card as Internal Storage Android Marshmallow (no Root)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZLV5STiAW8) and I failed. When I write "adb shell" in cmd, everything's ok. But on the next step, by writing "sm list-disks", this appears: /system/bin/sh: sm: not found

What can I do to fix that? The solution posted in one comment does not work (typing "adb shell sm list-disks" in one line).